# What will be the first language that has its own special Math.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, languages

Recently StackOverflow started a [Russian version of the site](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) because of the huge contribution of the Russians to the IT and English StackOverflow.

My question is:

If the SE management team decide to start Math.Stackexchange in a new language, what should that language be? How to choose it? What are the important parameters for choosing it?

I think possibly the number of original site users who speak a special language as natives is the key parameter here. As I found many Chinese people here, possibly Chinese language could be an option but I have no idea what the real status of native speakers of different countries is in Math.Stackexchange.

Another parameter could be the popularity of the site among different countries in the sense that the countries with large enough population that Math.Stackexchange is more popular in them with respect to the others, are more rightful to have a version of Math.Stackexchange in their own native language. Again, I have no idea about the statistical situation of the popularity of the site in different countries.

Any reference to related statistics could be also very helpful.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I don't think that this question is premature. Please see Normal Human's answer that says this year Math.Stackexchange was *so close* to become a multi-language site.

Comment: Why did people cast down-votes in this post?! Can somebody talk about the reasons?!

Comment: @Sarah Because, as I see it, it is undirected pointless pondering in a place meant for meaningful discussion about *this* site. Not about some hypothetical translation that may or may not come into existence the coming months and years. There's just no place for "Ooh, let's theorise about this exciting possibility" here. Oh, and I omitted the sugar coating because you didn't catch on the first time.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I really didn't understand what is wrong with my question. They added new languages to one of their popular sites and wants to do this for most of their other sites during a not too long term project and Math.Stackexchange is one of the first candidates. I'm asking about this very likely matter that may come to exists very soon. Why so angry commenting?

Answer (score 6):

My guess: Australian and Canadian, in this or the other order.

More seriously: see the post [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - SE 2.0 Sites edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition) which is the authoritative reference for this issue.

> In order for us to consider a localized site other than Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow must currently exist in the target language. Additionally, we positively must have community manager cycles to spare, from someone fluent in the target language.
>
> Currently, this is not the case for any language where Stack Overflow has been translated, and we don't foresee it being the case in the amount of time we're willing to ask people to wait.

See also [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition?lq=1) concerning the criteria for prioritizing languages.

---

By the way: earlier this year, SE was *so* close to getting Mathematics in Russian. They hired Nicolas Chabanovsky, the founder of Q&A network "Сеть Знаний" (`sezn.ru`, link now redirects), and acquired the network. This small network, modeled on Stack Exchange, consisted of three Q&A sites (plus "careers" site):

- Programming site Hashcode, imported into SE as https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
- Russian Language, imported into SE as https://rus.stackexchange.com/  (despite the fact that SE already had https://russian.stackexchange.com/)
- Mathematics site... was not  imported, it remains at http://math.hashcode.ru/

Nicolas explained the decision [in a meta post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150331044751/https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/research/2992/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-stack-exchange):

> Сообщество Математика продолжит развиваться независимо. Это связано с направленностью вопросов на форуме. В сообществе задается большое количество вопросов - домашних заданий, в то время как на ХэшКоде и Русском языке данный тип вопросов является неприемлемым.

which I translate as

> The Mathematics community will continue to develop independently. This is related to the scope of questions there. In this community a large number of homework questions are asked, while on HashCode and Russian Language  they are not allowed.

Indeed, visiting http://math.hashcode.ru/ one may observe that the site essentially consists of one user solving everyone's homework (or giving hints).

Comment: Can you add any information about the statistics related to the popularity of this site in different countries and the distribution of the native languages that Math.Stackexchange users speak?

Comment: That is a separate question, and it has been answered separately. [Is there statistic data of how many people access the site and from which country and what times?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13854)

Comment: Are the former users of `sezn.ru` imported as well, or not? For example, how one can access her/his imported account? I'm asking as a friend of one of users.

Comment: @firtree The users of imported sites (SO and Russian language) have been imported: see http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/24

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot!